# Javascript: Doesn't insert on right index row table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried adding a certain number of rows (depending on the number inputted on the textbox) under the row of which button was clicked. It works fine on the first row but it's not working when I do it on the second row button (it keeps on inserting under the first row).

Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/L4zffok1/

```
$('.add-rows').click(function(){

    var $bx_id;
    var $num_rows;
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    $bx_id = this.id;
    $num_rows = $('#num_boxcodes_'+$bx_id).val();

    for (i = 0; i < $num_rows; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow($bx_id);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
        var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
        cell1.innerHTML = '------';
        cell2.innerHTML = '------';
        cell3.innerHTML = '------';
        cell4.innerHTML = '------';
        cell5.innerHTML = '------';
        cell6.innerHTML = '------';
        cell7.innerHTML = '------';
        cell8.innerHTML = '------';
    }
});
```

Comment: your fiddle doesn't work at all because there's nothing with id like 'num_boxcodes_...`

Comment: once you've inserted the rows, the id for any existing rows below will no longer be relevant as to where to insert when that button is pressed ...

Comment: And the issue is the rownumber, the argument passed to `insertRow`. Once you add more rows the last row is pushed down and gets a new index based on the number of rows in the table. When you then pass `2` as a rownumber for the new rows, they are inserted in that row, which is before the last row. In other words, you have a serious logical flaw in your script.

Comment: Change "num_rows_" instead of "num_boxcodes_" in jquery where you're getting $num_rows, that will start adding cells.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong name of the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.insertRow` expects that you pass index at witch put your new rows, but instead you only pass `2` or `3` (that's the ID's, *ID name should not start with number*). Try calculating new position instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.add-rows').click(function() {

    var $bx_id;
    var $num_rows;
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    $bx_id = this.id;
    $num_rows = $('#num_rows_' + $bx_id).val();
    var rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 2;
    var k = "00" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    k = k.substr(k.length - 2);

    for (i = 0; i < $num_rows; i++) {
      var row = table.insertRow(rowIndex);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
      var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
      var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
      var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
      var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
      var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
      cell1.innerHTML = '----' + k;
      cell2.innerHTML = '----' + k;
      cell3.innerHTML = '----' + k;
      cell4.innerHTML = '----' + k;
      cell5.innerHTML = '----' + k;
      cell6.innerHTML = '----' + k;
      cell7.innerHTML = '----' + k;
      cell8.innerHTML = '----' + k;
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="success">
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
      <th>Column 6</th>
      <th>Column 7</th>
      <th>Column 8</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="10" id="num_rows_2" />
        <button type="button" id="2" class="btn btn-success btn-inline add-rows">OK</button>
      </td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test2</td>
      <td>Test2</td>
      <td>Test2</td>
      <td>Test2</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="10" id="num_rows_3" />
        <button type="button" id="3" class="btn btn-success btn-inline add-rows">OK</button>
      </td>
      <td>Test2</td>
      <td>Test2</td>
      <td>Test2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the id of the input control to be num_boxcodes_ and the function to add the rows and its work now:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.add-rows').click(function(){
  var $bx_id;
  var $num_rows;
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");  
       $num_rows = $('#num_boxcodes_'+this.id).val();
        $bx_id = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 2;

  for (i = 0; i < $num_rows; i++) {
   var row = table.insertRow($bx_id);
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
   var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
   var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
   var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
   var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
   var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
   var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
   var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
   cell1.innerHTML = '------';
   cell2.innerHTML = '------';
   cell3.innerHTML = '------';
   cell4.innerHTML = '------';
   cell5.innerHTML = '------';
   cell6.innerHTML = '------';
   cell7.innerHTML = '------';
   cell8.innerHTML = '------';
  }
 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="myTable">
   <thead>
    <tr class="success">
     <th>Column 1</th>
     <th>Column 2</th>
     <th>Column 3</th>
     <th>Column 4</th>
     <th>Column 5</th>
     <th>Column 6</th>
     <th>Column 7</th>
     <th>Column 8</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Test</td>
     <td>Test</td>
     <td>Test</td>
     <td>Test</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" size="10" id="num_boxcodes_2" />
      <button type="button" id="2" class="btn btn-success btn-inline add-rows">OK</button>
     </td>
     <td>Test</td>
     <td>Test</td>
     <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Test2</td>
     <td>Test2</td>
     <td>Test2</td>
     <td>Test2</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" size="10" id="num_boxcodes_3" />
    <button type="button" id="3" class="btn btn-success btn-inline add-rows">OK</button>
     </td>
     <td>Test2</td>
     <td>Test2</td>
     <td>Test2</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works! The difference of your code to mine was the calculation of the row index.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery, why not use it do create the new row based on the last one?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.add-rows').click(function(){
   var $bx_id;
   var $num_rows;
   var $table = $("#myTable");
   $num_rows = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
   for(i = 0; i < $num_rows; i++){
       var $newRow = $('<tr>');
       $newRow.html('<td>---------</td><td>---------</td><td>---------</td><td>---------</td><td>---------</td><td>---------</td><td>---------</td><td>---------</td>');
       $table.append($newRow)
   }
});
```

})

Comment: The number of child rows to be added is dependent on the value of the textbox of the parent row. So your solution won't work. Thanks anyways. :)

Comment: you're right - I missed that, edited the answer - now it's what you want

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet none of these answers work like you want, even if you chose one. Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/L4zffok1/4/

You are going to need to delegate Events to the new Elements, as well as turn off any Events previously attached. Recursion is the best solution for this.

```
function retardedAddRow(){
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  $('.add-rows').each(function(c, e){
    var t = $(e);
    t.off('click');
    t.click(function(){
      var val = t.prev().val(), row, cell;
      for(var n=0; n<val; n++){
        row = table.insertRow(c+2+n);
        for(var i=0,l=8; i<l; i++){
          cell = row.insertCell(i);
          cell.innerHTML = '------'; // bad technique
          if(i === 4){
            cell.innerHTML = "<input type='text' size='10' /><button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-inline add-rows'>OK</button>";
          }
        }
      }
      retardedAddRow();
    });
  });
}
$(function(){
  retardedAddRow();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But one of the answers here worked perfectly fine for what I needed. :)